# Speeding violations in France by UK registered car

Tags: france, driving, eu-citizens, fines

Ok now i was in France the previous weekend and was running late to make it for the euro tunnel back.
So i stepped on the accelerator and drove above the speed limit. WAZE didnt show me any speed cameras so i didnt bother to check the road signs.

Now i believe i have gone past a number of speed cams above the limit.

I am worried of what to do if i receive fines at home.

What will happen if i dont pay it??

Not proud of speeding but i did commit the stupid act. :(

Comment: UK license in France?!! Forget about it. Either you never receive a ticket in mail or if received it arrives as registered mail: you just refuse to accept the registered mail from French traffic offices.

Comment: I don't know why the UK should be different, I got a French speeding ticket sent to my German home address for being 1 km/h above the limit....

Comment: Ive just received 2 speeding fines in 2 weeks - one was from last October and one from January. Both in ordinary post to my UK address. They are obviously working through the backlog.

Comment: Note that the speed camera option in WAZE is illegal in France. The fine is 1500 euro's, which is higher than all speeding tickets!

Answer (score 4):

According to the AA, if you believe you have committed the offence you should pay the fine or face the real possibility of being chased for a much-increased penalty charge and probable travel difficulties in France in future. https://www.theaa.com/european-breakdown-cover/driving-in-europe/driving-offence-abroad